# .htaccess Only for PHP files

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am generating static webpages and using mod rewrite to generate nicer urls like so:

`.../idea/2-Lovely-Lavs`

To create this url I am using mod rewrite like so:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/idea/([^/]+)/?$ /idea.php?name=$1 [L]
```

However this is also rewrite all my img/js/css files, how do I prevent it rewriting these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. Just make sure the part of the URL after `idea/` does not have a dot `.` or a forward slash `/`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^idea/([^/\.]+)$ idea.php?name=$1 [L]
```